# How to deploy Drupal 8 to production?

Tags: 8, deployment, composer

I've got a Drupal 8 site in dev that was put together with composer. I think I've got a solid grasp on the dependency injection bit although the details are murky. Now I want to deploy it to production but I've heard grave warnings that composer is not to be run on production. How can I deploy my Drupal to without it?

I've come across Acquia's [BLT](https://github.com/acquia/blt) and it talks about building an artifact, maintaining it in a separate repo, and pulling that into production. I like the idea of generating a build artifact, but I'm not sure how to get one of those. I'm also not clear yet about how configuration is handled in that flow.

**Update:**
This is our first Drupal 8 site. With D7 we'd settled on uploading a drush archive for the initial deploy and bash scripts for updates.

What I'd like is to pull the production repository and import configuration. Actually, my dream workflow would be to make a commit that triggers the testing and auto-deploy process. I'm struggling with the tooling for that though.

Comment: Two things: this probably is going to depend mostly on how your infrastructure is setup in production. How do you deployment? How would you like to do deployments? Second, the only "grave warning" is that `composer update` uses a lot of memory so it is not ideal to run it in a production environment where resources may be needed elsewhere or your PHP process is memory-limited. `composer install` is fine to run in production because it does not need to calculate dependencies.

Comment: @mradcliffe I updated the question with some additional details and wishful thinking. Do you know if there are guidelines for deployment workflows? Qualities that they should all share to be 'good enough'?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I updated the question, is it good enough to be un-held?

Comment: @ponies It's still a good question.Years later (2020-04-28) I tried to answer this here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/293147/80164